# Update widget on day change

Tags: android

I have a widget that displays the current date among other things. However the widget only gets updated when a user performs an action in the main activity.

How would I go about forcing the widget to update the next time the phone is turned on after midnight to reflect the new date?

I understand I may need an AlarmManager but I'm not clear on the parameters. And do I put it in my main activity and have it call the method that calls update on my widget?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in a similar style, I have a service that I want to run at a certain time.  when this service has done it's work it then updates my widget and stops itself (the service).  here is a snippet of how I launch my service at a specified time

```
Intent mSrvcIntent = new Intent(packageContext, MyService.class);
PendingIntent mSrvcPendingingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(packageContext,0, mSrvcIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(android.content.Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
mAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time to start service, mSrvcPendingingIntent);
```

I hope this is near enough for you to be able to solve your problem

Comment: I need one help Where it is define this alarm manager in our application.

Answer (score 1):

ad this to your manifest widget receiver

```
 <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED" />...
```

onReceive() will fire

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET"/>
</intent-filter>
```